# SIGSEGV at Boot (SurfaceFlinger?)

Tags: boot, system-freeze

I recently installed (with Odin) the latest stock ROM for my SGS2 without wiping data.
After that I put a rooted kernel and started using.

I found out that:
- if I boot the phone, let it get to the lock screen (the first to appear after Samsung logo) and then turn off screen with power button, all goes fine
- if I don't turn screen off, the boot proccess goes wrong and all freeze; I can only force boot it again.

I took logcat of both boots and found these errors in the faulty one.
NB: I cut some parts of the SIGSEGV to remain within 30000 characters limit.

Can anybody help fix the problem?

Thank you!!!

```
E/UsimServiceTable: isActive for service 51 fails, max service is 40
E/UsimServiceTable: isSSTAvailable for service 51 fails, max service is 80
E/UsimServiceTable: isActive for service 51 fails, max service is 40
E/UsimServiceTable: isSSTAvailable for service 51 fails, max service is 80
E/UsimServiceTable: isActive for service 52 fails, max service is 40
E/UsimServiceTable: isSSTAvailable for service 52 fails, max service is 80
E/UsimServiceTable: isActive for service 52 fails, max service is 40
E/UsimServiceTable: isSSTAvailable for service 52 fails, max service is 80
E/UsimServiceTable: isActive for service 53 fails, max service is 40
E/UsimServiceTable: isSSTAvailable for service 53 fails, max service is 80
E/UsimServiceTable: isActive for service 53 fails, max service is 40
E/UsimServiceTable: isSSTAvailable for service 53 fails, max service is 80
E/UsimServiceTable: isActive for service 54 fails, max service is 40
E/UsimServiceTable: isSSTAvailable for service 54 fails, max service is 80
E/UsimServiceTable: isActive for service 54 fails, max service is 40
E/UsimServiceTable: isSSTAvailable for service 54 fails, max service is 80
E/UsimServiceTable: isActive for service 55 fails, max service is 40
E/UsimServiceTable: isSSTAvailable for service 55 fails, max service is 80
E/UsimServiceTable: isActive for service 55 fails, max service is 40
E/UsimServiceTable: isSSTAvailable for service 55 fails, max service is 80

E/android.os.Debug: !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_sys_watchdog
E/Watchdog: WATCHDOG caused by com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService

E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
E/AndroidRuntime: android.os.DeadObjectException
E/AndroidRuntime:   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:3305)
E/AndroidRuntime:   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:121)
E/AndroidRuntime:   at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
E/AndroidRuntime:   at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
E/AndroidRuntime:   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/Sensors : sensorservice died [0x4c38d570]

E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10012 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.
E/AndroidRuntime:   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
E/AndroidRuntime:   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
E/AndroidRuntime:   at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.getCellLocation(ITelephony.java:1261)
E/AndroidRuntime:   at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getCellLocation(TelephonyManager.java:267)
E/AndroidRuntime:   at ekv.a(SourceFile:53)
E/AndroidRuntime:   at com.google.android.location.os.real.SdkSpecific8.a(SourceFile:62)
E/AndroidRuntime:   at ekl.handleMessage(SourceFile:187)
E/AndroidRuntime:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime:   at eko.run(SourceFile:804)
E/AndroidRuntime:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

E/BootAnimation: sequence and loop RBG type's are different. seqeunce:7,loop:6

E/BootAnimation: /sys/class/sec/led/led_pattern: open error, fd = -1

E/SECHWC_LOG: int hwc_device_open(const hw_module_t*, char const*, hw_device_t**)::window_set_pos is failed : Bad address
E/SECHWC_LOG: int destroyMem(s3c_mem_t*)::invalied fd(0) fail
E/SECHWC_LOG: int hwc_device_open(const hw_module_t*, char const*, hw_device_t**)::destroyMem() fail
E/SurfaceFlinger: composer device failed to initialize (Invalid argument)
D/SurfaceFlinger: About to give-up screen, flinger = 0x4193cd78
F/libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00002900 (code=1), thread 4408 (SurfaceFlinger)
I/SurfaceFlinger: EventThread ready to run.
I/BootAnimation: ret=2, fps:12, interval:83333
E/BootAnimation: sequence and loop RBG type's are different. seqeunce:7,loop:6
I/BootAnimation: createSurface BGRA8888
I/ServiceManager: service 'nfc' died
I/ServiceManager: service 'iphonesubinfo' died
I/ServiceManager: service 'com.orange.authentication.simcard' died
I/ServiceManager: service 'isms' died
I/ServiceManager: service 'phoneext' died
I/ServiceManager: service 'phone' died
I/ServiceManager: service 'sip' died
I/ServiceManager: service 'simphonebook' died
V/AudioPolicyManagerBase: releaseOutput() 2
I/DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'samsung/GT-I9100P/GT-I9100P:4.1.2/JZO54K/I9100PXXLSK:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   : pid: 4403, tid: 4408, name: SurfaceFlinger  >>> /system/bin/surfaceflinger <<<
I/DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00002900
D/dalvikvm: Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 155 unimplemented (abstract) methods
I/DEBUG   :     r0 41953580  r1 00000001  r2 419442e8  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG   :     r4 419531c0  r5 00002901  r6 00000001  r7 4193d730
I/DEBUG   :     r8 4105ecac  r9 00000001  sl 4193d72c  fp 0000000d
I/DEBUG   :     ip 401d0168  sp 4105ec60  lr 400c33bf  pc 00002900  cpsr 20000030
I/DEBUG   :     d0  3f00000000000000  d1  00000000437f0000
I/DEBUG   :     d2  437f00003f000000  d3  437f8000000000ff
I/DEBUG   :     d4  c0000000437f0000  d5  3f800000bf800000
I/DEBUG   :     d6  3f8000003f800000  d7  00ffffff3f800000
I/DEBUG   :     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   :     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   :     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   :     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   :     d16 7fffffffffffffff  d17 7fffffffffffffff
I/DEBUG   :     d18 0000000000000000  d19 3fe0000000000000
I/DEBUG   :     d20 3fe000000000946f  d21 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   :     d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   :     d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   :     d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   :     d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   :     d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   :     scr 60000010
I/DEBUG   : 
I/DEBUG   : backtrace:
I/DEBUG   :     #00  pc 00002900  <unknown>
I/DEBUG   :     #01  pc 000203bd  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::HWComposer::commit() const+14)
I/DEBUG   :     #02  pc 0001fd05  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::DisplayHardware::flip(android::Region const&) const+60)
I/DEBUG   :     #03  pc 00022f8f  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::SurfaceFlinger::onScreenReleased()+70)
I/DEBUG   :     #04  pc 00022fb9  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so
I/DEBUG   :     #05  pc 00020d4b  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::MessageBase::handleMessage(android::Message const&)+12)
I/DEBUG   :     #06  pc 000149e3  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+426)
I/DEBUG   :     #07  pc 00014b01  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+104)
I/DEBUG   :     #08  pc 000210d9  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::MessageQueue::waitMessage()+40)
I/DEBUG   :     #09  pc 00021991  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::SurfaceFlinger::threadLoop()+4)
I/DEBUG   :     #10  pc 0001104f  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+114)
I/DEBUG   :     #11  pc 00010bb5  /system/lib/libutils.so
I/DEBUG   :     #12  pc 00012e00  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
I/DEBUG   :     #13  pc 00012558  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
I/DEBUG   : 
I/DEBUG   : stack:
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec20  41944370  [heap]
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec24  410942d0  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so (_gles_clear+1148)
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec28  00000001  
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec2c  00000001  
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec30  00000001  
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec34  41943a10  [heap]
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec38  0000ff00  
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec3c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec40  00000000  
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec44  00000000  
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec48  00000000  
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec4c  ff000000  
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec50  00000000  
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec54  00000000  
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec58  df0027ad  
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec5c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   :     #00  4105ec60  41953580  [heap]
I/DEBUG   :          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   :     #01  4105ec60  41953580  [heap]
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec64  4193db00  [heap]
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec68  419442e8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec6c  400c2d09  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::DisplayHardware::flip(android::Region const&) const+64)
I/DEBUG   :     #02  4105ec70  4193db00  [heap]
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec74  4105ecac  
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec78  00000007  
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec7c  40241d00  /system/lib/libui.so
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec80  4193db00  [heap]
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec84  4193cd78  [heap]
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec88  400c3d3f  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::MessageBase::handleMessage(android::Message const&))
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec8c  4193d730  [heap]
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec90  40193ebe  /system/lib/libutils.so
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec94  400c5f93  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::SurfaceFlinger::onScreenReleased()+74)
I/DEBUG   : 
I/DEBUG   : memory near r0:
```

[.........................]

```
I/DEBUG   : 
I/DEBUG   : memory map around fault addr 00002900:
I/DEBUG   :     (no map below)
I/DEBUG   :     (no map for address)
I/DEBUG   :     4000e000-4000f000 /system/lib/libstdc++.so
I/SamplingProfilerIntegration: Profiling disabled.
I/Zygote  : !@beginofpreloadClasses()
I/Zygote  : Preloading classes...
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
I/Zygote  : !@beginofpreloadResources()
D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 40K, 80% free 528K/2560K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 3ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 2ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 80% free 527K/2560K, paused 10ms+0ms, total 13ms
E/installd: eof
E/installd: failed to read size
I/installd: closing connection
I/Zygote  : Preloading resources...
I/Zygote  : Number of total Classes to prelaod: 2309
I/Zygote  : Classes to load for thread1 0~830
I/Zygote  : Classes to load for thread2 831~2308
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.InputQueue$FinishedCallback
I/DEBUG   : !@dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_native -m 4403
I/dumpstate: begin
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 83K, 63% free 956K/2560K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.animation.ValueAnimator$2
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.animation.ValueAnimator$3
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.animation.ValueAnimator$4
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.animation.ValueAnimator$5
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 28K, 44% free 1439K/2560K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 74K, 27% free 1870K/2560K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.ViewRootImpl$3
V/BluetoothAudioGateway.cpp: classInitNative
V/BT HSHFP: classInitNative
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 40K, 10% free 2312K/2560K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8K, 8% free 2361K/2560K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 7% free 2982K/3203K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.content.res.Resources$1
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 15K, 2% free 3659K/3715K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 2% free 4027K/4099K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 3% free 5049K/5187K, paused 5ms, total 6ms
I/dalvikvm: threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libwebcore.so)
D/dalvikvm: No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libchromium_net.so 0x0, skipping init
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 14K, 1% free 6325K/6339K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 30K, 2% free 7019K/7107K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
I/Zygote  : ...preloaded 279 resources in 604ms.
I/Zygote  : ...preloaded 31 resources in 7ms.
I/Zygote  : !@End of preloadResources()
D/TextLayoutCache: Using debug level = 0 - Debug Enabled = 0
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.widget.EdgeGlow
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$DatabaseReentrantLock
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.media.AudioManager$2
I/dalvikvm: threadid=6: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)
D/MtpDeviceJNI: register_android_mtp_MtpDevice
I/dalvikvm: threadid=6: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)
I/dalvikvm: threadid=6: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.media.IRemoteControlClientDispatcher
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.media.IRemoteControlClientDispatcher$Stub
D/su      : su invoked. 
D/su      : Allowing shell. 
D/su      : 2000 /system/bin/dumpstate executing 0 lsof using binary lsof : lsof 
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.widget.TextView$Blink
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.widget.TextView$EasyEditSpanController
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.widget.TextView$InputContentType
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.widget.TextView$InputMethodState
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.widget.TextView$TextAlign
E/PhonePolicy: Could not preload class for phone policy: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 308K, 4% free 8526K/8835K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.os.Power
V/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp: classInitNative
V/BluetoothService.cpp: classInitNative
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.text.TextDirectionHeuristics$CharCount
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.text.method.WordIterator$1
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.InputHandler
I/Zygote  : ...preloaded 831 classes in 1146ms.
I/System  : Loaded time zone names for  in 312ms (309ms in ICU)
I/System  : Loaded time zone names for en_US in 93ms (89ms in ICU)
I/System  : Loaded time zone names for it_IT in 101ms (97ms in ICU)
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 977K, 10% free 9650K/10627K, paused 24ms, total 25ms
I/Zygote  : ...preloaded 1478 classes in 1495ms.
I/Zygote  : !@EndofpreloadClasses()
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 327K, 12% free 9360K/10627K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 21ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 21K, 13% free 9339K/10627K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 18ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 13% free 9339K/10627K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 17ms
I/dalvikvm: System server process 4440 has been created
I/Zygote  : Accepting command socket connections
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020003 (t=1 e=3) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020000 (t=1 e=0) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020001 (t=1 e=1) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020001 (t=1 e=1) in package 0 (error -75)
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 109K, 13% free 9750K/11143K, paused 12ms+12ms, total 84ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 21ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 21ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 21ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 20ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 7ms
I/sysproc : !@beginofsystem_init1()
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020005 (t=1 e=5) in package 0 (error -75)
I/sysproc : Entered system_init()
I/sysproc : ServiceManager: 0x4c24d3c8
D/SensorService: nuSensorService starting...
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f0201f5 (t=1 e=501) in package 0 (error -75)
I/AKMD2   : open_accelerometer
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f0201f5 (t=1 e=501) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f0201f4 (t=1 e=500) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020001 (t=1 e=1) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020004 (t=1 e=4) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020007 (t=1 e=7) in package 0 (error -75)
I/PackageParser: com.orange.authentication.simcard.permission: compat added android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f02001b (t=1 e=27) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f02001b (t=1 e=27) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f040001 (t=3 e=1) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f02001d (t=1 e=29) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f040000 (t=3 e=0) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020007 (t=1 e=7) in package 0 (error -75)
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 168K, 13% free 10138K/11591K, paused 23ms+3ms, total 60ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 15ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 16ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 16ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 17ms
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f02025f (t=1 e=607) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f02032c (t=1 e=812) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f02032f (t=1 e=815) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f02022c (t=1 e=556) in package 0 (error -75)
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 215K, 13% free 10473K/11975K, paused 37ms+2ms, total 55ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 32ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 35ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 23ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 26ms
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f02022c (t=1 e=556) in package 0 (error -75)
I/SensorService: K3DH Acceleration Sensor
I/SensorService: AK8975 Magnetic field Sensor
I/SensorService: AK8975 Orientation Sensor
I/SensorService: CM3663 Light Sensor
I/SensorService: CM3663 Proximity Sensor
I/SensorService: K3G Gyroscope Sensor
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f0204f6 (t=1 e=1270) in package 0 (error -75)
I/RemoteDesktopService: RemoteDesktopService started (pid=4440)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f0204f6 (t=1 e=1270) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f0204f6 (t=1 e=1270) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f110062 (t=16 e=98) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020000 (t=1 e=0) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f110062 (t=16 e=98) in package 0 (error -75)
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 259K, 13% free 10749K/12295K, paused 30ms, total 31ms
D/SensorService: nuSensorService thread starting...
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f02000c (t=1 e=12) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f02001a (t=1 e=26) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f0203c1 (t=1 e=961) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f0203c1 (t=1 e=961) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f03003b (t=2 e=59) in package 0 (error -75)
I/PackageParser: com.monotype.android.font.helvneuelt: compat added android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 252K, 13% free 11009K/12551K, paused 11ms+2ms, total 43ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 14ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 15ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 14ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 15ms
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020000 (t=1 e=0) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020000 (t=1 e=0) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020000 (t=1 e=0) in package 0 (error -75)
D/su      : su invoked. 
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020004 (t=1 e=4) in package 0 (error -75)
D/su      : Allowing shell. 
D/su      : 2000 /system/bin/dumpstate executing 0 sqlite3 using binary sqlite3 : sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db pragma user_version; select * from system; select * from secure; 
E/su      : exec failed with 2: No such file or directory 
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 241K, 12% free 11274K/12807K, paused 1ms+4ms, total 26ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 2ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 3ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 3ms
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020332 (t=1 e=818) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020334 (t=1 e=820) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020334 (t=1 e=820) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020334 (t=1 e=820) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020333 (t=1 e=819) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020333 (t=1 e=819) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020333 (t=1 e=819) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020009 (t=1 e=9) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f02001d (t=1 e=29) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020333 (t=1 e=819) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f10004b (t=15 e=75) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f02035d (t=1 e=861) in package 0 (error -75)
D/su      : su invoked. 
D/su      : Allowing shell. 
D/su      : 2000 /system/bin/dumpstate executing 0 netcfg using binary netcfg : netcfg 
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020319 (t=1 e=793) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020319 (t=1 e=793) in package 0 (error -75)
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 294K, 13% free 11541K/13127K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 53ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 17ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 18ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 18ms
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020331 (t=1 e=817) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020328 (t=1 e=808) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020328 (t=1 e=808) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020328 (t=1 e=808) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f02014e (t=1 e=334) in package 0 (error -75)
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 280K, 12% free 11809K/13383K, paused 11ms+3ms, total 45ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 18ms
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f0e004d (t=13 e=77) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f0e004e (t=13 e=78) in package 0 (error -75)
I/BootTime: Prefetch Time Taken:1050
D/su      : su invoked. 
D/su      : Allowing shell. 
D/su      : 2000 /system/bin/dumpstate executing 0 iptables using binary iptables : iptables -L -nvx 
D/su      : su invoked. 
D/su      : Allowing shell. 
D/su      : 2000 /system/bin/dumpstate executing 0 ip6tables using binary ip6tables : ip6tables -L -nvx 
D/su      : su invoked. 
D/su      : Allowing shell. 
D/su      : 2000 /system/bin/dumpstate executing 0 iptables using binary iptables : iptables -t nat -L -nvx 
D/su      : su invoked. 
D/su      : Allowing shell. 
D/su      : 2000 /system/bin/dumpstate executing 0 iptables using binary iptables : iptables -t raw -L -nvx 
D/su      : su invoked. 
D/su      : Allowing shell. 
D/su      : 2000 /system/bin/dumpstate executing 0 ip6tables using binary ip6tables : ip6tables -t raw -L -nvx 
D/su      : su invoked. 
D/su      : Allowing shell. 
D/su      : 2000 /system/bin/dumpstate executing 0 wpa_cli using binary wpa_cli : wpa_cli list_networks 
E/su      : exec failed with 2: No such file or directory 
D/VoldCmdListener: asec list
D/su      : su invoked. 
D/su      : Allowing shell. 
D/su      : 2000 /system/bin/dumpstate executing 0 cat using binary cat : cat /data/system/packages.xml 
D/su      : su invoked. 
D/su      : Allowing shell. 
D/su      : 2000 /system/bin/dumpstate executing 0 cat using binary cat : cat /proc/4403/maps 
I/dumpstate: done
I/ServiceManager: service 'SurfaceFlinger' died
I/ServiceManager: service 'SecTVOutService' died
F/libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000010 (code=1), thread 4423 (BootAnimation)
D/BootAnimation: SurfaceFlinger died, exiting...
F/libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 4440 (system_server)
I/ServiceManager: service 'sensorservice' died
I/DEBUG   : unexpected waitpid response: n=4440, status=00000009
I/DEBUG   : ptrace detach from 4440 failed: No such process
I/DEBUG   : debuggerd committing suicide to free the zombie!
I/DEBUG   : debuggerd: Mar  7 2013 21:50:41
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the ROM has the wrong drivers for your hardware. Most likely, this ROM is for an SGS2 with the exynos4 SoC, but your SGS2 has a different SoC. Be aware that Samsung sells different hardware in the same case with the same name: only the model number is different. Double-check whether the ROM is for exactly the same variant of the SGS2 that you have.

Comment: No, I'm sure: I put the lastest ROM from my operator (TIM) that's the only one that sells the i9100P variant in Italy (ie i9100 + NFC).
Plus how could it work turning screen off during boot?

Is there anyway to check SoC mismatch, just in case?

Comment: Wait a minute: the kernel I used could be from a different ROM... How can I be sure what driver the kernel has?

Comment: @p.dario If it's from your operator, it should be the right one. If you've got the wrong kernel, that would explain it too. Flash the right kernel and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Mmm... The kernel is for i9100 that is said to be identical ti my i9100P apart from NFC functions. I also see the phone does not always freeze if leaved untouched. Wouldn't a driver issue freeze the phone no matter what?